# optimal spacing for stove pipe heat shield

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation

Note: Question is DIY'ish, but analysis seems pretty theoretical, if less so than typical for this site (I'm new to it). Should I move to "engineering" site ?

The flue for my wood stove transitions from a simple single-wall stove pipe to a "metalbestos" chimney as it passes through the floor of a loft.  The chimney then passes through the ceiling of the loft and out the roof. Along the way, it passes within 1" of the wooden railing of the loft (see photo below).   This is problematic, because the metalbestos chimney is spec'd for minimum 2" from combustible building material.  It has been this way for many years, without difficulty; in fact, the chimney barely gets too hot to touch with a raging fire; I suspect the 2" spec is for the event of a chimney-fire.

I would like to address the issue by putting a heat shield of some kind between the chimney and the loft railing (specifically, the part that is within 1", a horizontal fir 2x6).  I imagine a sheet of aluminum, roughly 8" square, attached to the 2x6 with woodscrews and standoff spacers.   The question: what is the optimal distance of this shield from the 2x6, that is, how is the 1" space divided between the chimney-to-shield gap and the shield-to-2x6 gap ?  (Optimal, of course, meaning to minimize heating of the 2x6).

[image]

Comment: Intuition suggests halfway is the answer: 1/2" from both the chimney and the 2x6.

Comment: I imagine the answer lies in analyzing the radiant heat transfer across the two gaps using the Stafen-Boltzman law.  But it's then it's also necessary to quantify the heat loss of the shield via both convection, and conduction of heat from the part of the shield at the 1" gap to its periphery (it's 8" square to shield the entire 8" diameter of the chimney and the 5.5" height of the 2x6).

Comment: Perhaps the key lies in maximizing the heat transfer (via conduction) from the "pinch point" where the gap is only 1", to the periphery of the shield.  So there's a trade-off of a thicker shield conducting heat better but eating into the available spacing.   And maybe it's worth using copper (roughly double the heat conductance of aluminum).

Comment: So, no one wants to attempt to answer my question ?

Answer (score 1):

Physics cannot override the building code. If it was installed improperly to begin with, the pipe must be repositioned or shielded with a UL-approved device, and signed off by an inspector. This is definitively NOT the domain of the do-it-yourselfer.

Comment: This is not subject to inspection at this point, though I agree that the installation was done improperly (and incompetently inspected).  I realize the right answer is to move the pipe and/or the wood so that the gap is 2".  This could be done, without too much trouble, by cutting out a 1ft wide piece of the 2x6 and splicing it with another piece on the back side.   And I may well do it that way.    Nonetheless, I think doing in the other way (the wrong way, perhaps) makes for an interesting problem of analysis, and was curious what the folks here could come up with.

Comment: Agree. just don't burn your house down! this happened to a friend in vermont- improper clearance to a flue pipe, never inspected, 10 years later his house burnt down, and he lost everything.

Comment: I've heard that wood becomes more flammable if it is exposed to heat for months or years.

Comment: Keith, I've heard of that too; is it maybe "pyrolysis" ?   My installation has been like this for 31 years with no problems (and heating almost exclusively with wood).   On the other hand, my installation has been like this for 31 years ...

Comment: Here's the rub: If the house catches fire for any reason, and your insurance carrier discovers an out-of-code flue pipe installation, they'll void your fire insurance coverage.

Comment: Ok.  Certainly easier to try to alter 2x6 than pipe.  Saw out a small chunk so no wood within 2".  How to restore structural integrity of 2x6 ?   Maybe 1-1/2" wide strips of steel screwed to top & bottom.